# route53 refuse my dns query will it be recovered with time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I try to use amazon route53 with purchasing domain from them (eg. example.com).

before domain name registration done, I tried to create hosted zone setting, and add some subdomains (eg. api.example.com).

after I add subdomains, I realize another hosted zone record for same domain created, but I delete it (I guess that is the mistake).

then my dns query is only resolved with name server which is set in my hosted zone setting as NS record. both from google dns (8.8.8.8) and amazon dns which is not contained in NS record (ns-xxxx.awsdns-yy.org).

strange thing is, when I debug DNS resolve process like http://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/api.example.com, amazon name server which try to respond to query is different from servers in my NS record. and they seems to reject query.

that is because I didn't wait for hosted zone record automatically create? 
if so, how to resolve the issue? just wait for 2 days (I think authority server data expires) or need to contact AWS guys?

adding name servers appeared in response of http://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com seems no help.

regards,

Comment: What kinds of records are you making?

Comment: A records which has 3 ip addresses.

Comment: Do you have a NS record in Route 53 for `example.com` ? (not entirely sure it's required if you buy the record from amazon directly but sounds like it should be there in some form)

Comment: @apokryfos I think NS record exists in hosted zone setting. it has 4 dns server domain name entries like ns-XXX.awsdns-YY.net.
ns-XXX.awsdns-YY.com.
ns-XXX.awsdns-YY.org.
ns-XXX.awsdns-YY.co.uk.

Comment: and seems only with above 4 DNS, my domain name can be resolved correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you need to contact Amazon for more information. Normally DNS lookups propagate, but it seems that some DNS server somewhere think it knows how to resolve the DNS of `example.com` so the request does not propagate to your actual NS set DNS servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deleted the hosted zone that Route 53 *registrar* created, but the settings telling the Internet which nameservers should be queried for your domain are still pointing to the nameservers that were associated with it.

In the Route 53 console, click "Registered Domains."

Select your domain.

Choose "add/edit name servers."

Enter the correct values for the Route 53 name servers from your current hosted zone, which you'll see when you click on the domain from the Hosted Zones page.

Comment: thanks! problem seems to be gone. I'm so dumb that cannot notice "add/edit name servers." link.

Comment: I also missed where it was. In the "details" pane of the registered domains panel, click the "Actions" drop down in the top right corner. "edit name servers" is the first item in the list.